# Error while removing the trailing comma using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var checked1 = JSON.parse(Cookies.get('checkedValues'));
```

Now the checked1 contains:     **,1**

I used the following code to remove the trailing comma.

```
var checked = checked1.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
```

But now i'm getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: checked1.replace is not a function

Comment: try first remove the comma the JSON.parse it.

Comment: *"Now the checked1 contains: ,1"* <- I highly doubt that unless you're referring to a property value within the `checked1` **object**

Comment: You cannot use the replace function on an object, only a string. JSON.parse() [returns an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: thank you Brian.. it workss.... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var checked1 = JSON.parse(Cookies.get('checkedValues').replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checked1 = JSON.parse(Cookies.get('checkedValues')).toString();
```

It Worked. The question was actually answered by Brian. But he removed his answer.

Comment: var checked= JSON.stringify(checkedValue);

Cookies.set('checkedValues', checked);

//cookie was set using JSON.stringify.

Comment: If it is already stringify , you can replace the ,1 without parseing the cookie..

Comment: is it? anyway now the problem solved. thank you for the suggestion.